# MONTHS_BETWEEN function is not recognized

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Microsoft SQL server 2008

```
select months_between
   (TO_DATE('1992-09-12','yyyy','mm','dd'), TO_DATE('1991-08-23','yyyy','mm','dd') ) "months"
   from sales
```

Help

Comment: it is showing Months_between is not a recognized function.

Comment: It is an Oracle function, not a SQL Server one.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server 2008, Use [`DATEDIFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, '23-08-1991', '12-09-1992') as "months"
FROM sales
```

I think `MONTHS_BETWEEN` is oracle.

Answer (score 2):

never heard of months_between in TSQL.

i usually go like this (using the dates you provided in your code):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '23-8-1991', '12-9-1992')
```

Answer (score 2):

`MONTHS_BETWEEN` is Oracle specific.  The equivalent of Oracle's `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function in SQL Server is the [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.  The `DATEDIFF` function returns the number of date and time boundaries crossed between two specified dates and it takes 3 arguments:

`DATEDIFF ( datepart, startdate, enddate )`